# (iPhone) Instruments can't "Attach to Process"

Tags: iphone, debugging, instruments, memory-leaks

Actually, I'm using a second generation Ipod Touch.
What I'm trying to do is to debug my app on XCode and look for any memory leaks on Instruments at the same time. Is it even possible? Because the "Attach to Process" submenu lists when my app is running (or debugging in this case) but all the items inside this menu are disabled.

All I can do is start the app from Instruments but later I come across some bug and I want to see the variables and properties affected. I'm also new to Instruments.

Please, could someone give me any advice? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex,

I would recommend this tutorial since it is one of the better ones for explaining how to use Instruments:

http://www.mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/

It can be very confusing at first, but take the time to get to know it and it'll ease a lot of headaches later.

Rob